# How do I access login information in Hybris?

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, backoffice

I need to extend my Backoffice login form and add two new fields to it. Then I need to access the login info in my Java code.

[Extending Backoffice Login Page](https://help.hybris.com/6.0.0/hcd/8bdb6cdd86691014b68ecffbbdd73817.html) says I need to use LoginInformationHandler.

I haven't found information on how to do this. Should I inject it as Spring bean? I can't see configuration for it in spring-xml files in my application or OOTB. The only constructor available needs TypedSettingsMap loginInfo, which would just create new LoginInfoHandler or something like that.

So, what's the solution for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, [LoginInformationHandler](https://help.hybris.com/6.3.0/api/backofficeframework/com/hybris/cockpitng/handler/login/LoginInformationHandler.html) is a service that you can inject into your service / facade.

Then, you would need to get the data like this:

```
loginInformationHandler.getLoginInformation(“tenant”);
```

Comment: the system says loginInformationHandler bean can't be found

Comment: @ИванИванов I see. Feel free to unaccept the answer. I assumed it was so, based on the Help guide.

Comment: got any tips on how I could resolve this? I've already tried creating custom backoffice extension and the thing is the same. seems, like I need to add cockpitng dependency to my extension

Comment: @ИванИванов I just tested, and it's OK. It can be used here custombackoffice/resources/custombackoffice-backoffice-spring.xml, not in custombackoffice/resources/custombackoffice-spring.xml.

Comment: @ИванИванов It has to be in the backoffice context. Feel free to upvote and accept again, if it's good for you. :)

Comment: yeah. thanks. the thing is, one should use it in backoffice/src, though. it won't be resolved in src. as it's only available in backoffice context

Comment: @ИванИванов Yes, you can use it in backoffice/src. Give it a try. :) It doesn't work under src.

Comment: already did. however, right now I'm facing another issue. As I needed LoginInfoHandler and I could only use it in a custom backoffice extension, I had to relocate my Services from core extension to custom backoffice extension. Now, even after adding dependency for custom backoffice extension to my facade extension, it's services cannot be imported and I get compilation errors. I'm using extensioninfo.xml file. also, <meta key="backoffice-module" value="true"/> line is declared in it. I'd appreciate your help, for sure.

Comment: @ИванИванов I'm not very familiar with backoffice yet, and I suggest to post that as a new question (since it's now another concern), so that the others can also chime in to help. :)